# crossing borders of tables: language role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to development, and have spent the last 12 hours (literally) trying to figure out this error message - I'm giving up for the night, but not before a quick cry for help to stackoverflow.

I have this form:

```
<h2>Select from the language options below (or, <%= button_to "Login", 'users/login', method: :get %></h2>

<%= form_for @language_role do |f| %>

    <div id="input">
      <h3>I want to learn:</h3><%= select_tag(:language_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Language.all, :id, :lang_name)) %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p><%= f.submit "Start learning" %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

which is giving me this error message, highlighting the line `@language_role = current_user.language_roles.build` : "undefined method `language_roles' for nil:NilClass"

I have three tables:

```
  create_table "language_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "language_id"
    t.boolean  "is_active"
    t.boolean  "is_teacher"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_language_roles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "languages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "lang_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

The `language_roles` table is meant to allow a user to have many languages, as well as many roles within that language. Here are my class definitions:

```
class LanguageRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :languages
  belongs_to :users
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :language_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :language_roles
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :language_roles
  has_many :languages, :through => :language_roles
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My root path goes to 'home#index', where the user is supposed to pick a language if `current_user.language_roles` is empty. As such, I put this code in my home controller and language_roles controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @language_role = current_user.language_roles.build
      end
    end

class LanguageRolesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @language_role = current_user.language_roles.build(language_role_params)
    if @language_role.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private

  def language_role_params
    params.permit(:language_id)
  end
end
```

What in the hell is the problem?? I assume I need to instantiate the variable somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Is the user logged in at that point? I'm guessing you cannot get any information from current user, like id (current_user.id) or anything like that?  How is current user being set?  It does not look like anything is providing that data to the view.  "for nil:NilClass" means that current_user is empty so I would start there.

Comment: ahhhh great call... I'll go check that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your `LanguageRole` Model:

```
LanguageRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :languages
  belongs_to :users
end
```

should be

```
LanguageRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`belongs_to` associations must use the singular term.
The name of the other model is pluralized when declaring a `has_many` association.

Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: ahh, thank you - I fixed it, but I'm still getting the same error on the "language_roles" method: "NoMethodError in HomeController#index
undefined method `language_roles' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Go first and create user. http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up . When you create user add some logic in your home index views. Something like: 
`<% if current_user %>
<%= form_for @language_role do |f| %>
......
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
    <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>`

In your home controller add this: `before_action :authenticate_user!`

Comment: You helped me get the error message to change, so that's good! Now the error message highlights  `<%= form_for @language_role do |f| %>`, saying "undefined method `language_roles_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fce05172610>:0x007fce03c9c0b0>".  I was getting this error message earlier today during this marathon debugging session - I never explicitly defined any "path" routes, so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: I DID IT! I DID IT! I had my :language_roles resources defined in the singular... oh the irony...

Answer (score 0):

Your current_user is not defines it seems. You can install a gem called ['pry-rails'](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) and debug your way out of this situation and any other in future. Here's a tutorial how to use it [Railscasts #280](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails)

Answer (score 0):

In your `LanguageRole` model you defined like `belongs_to :users`. But it should be `belongs_to :user`.

Your model look like ...

```
LanguageRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :languages
  belongs_to :users
end
```

Which should be something like

```
LanguageRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Thanks - just fixed it, but I'm still getting the same error: "NoMethodError in HomeController#index
undefined method `language_roles' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Your `current_user`  method is getting `nil` value ... that means your `current_user`  method is not getting the current user. Please make sure you have logged in.